# How to I grab the values off a .json file for discord.js? (deeper explanation in desc.)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I'm currently making a command where a random percentage and race or ethnicity pops up at the end, but the issue I'm facing is that I'm rather uncertain on how to grab the names of the ethnicities out of the .json file and make them show up.

This is the current coding:

```
const dna = require("../dna.json")
    
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => { 
        if (message.author.bot) return;
            number = 100
            percentage = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) +1;

            dnaNumber = 5
            dnaResults = Math.floor (Math.random() * (dnaNumber - 1 + 1)) +1;
        
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                embed.setTitle('DNA Test ')
                embed.setColor('RANDOM')
                embed.setDescription('You are ' + percentage + '% ' + dnaResults + '!')
                embed.setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(embed)
        
};
```

...and this is what is shot out by the bot:
[DNA Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfo0N.png)

The .json file appears like this:

```
{
    "jewish": "Jewish",
    "black": "Black",
    "hispanic": "Hispanic",
    "british": "British",
    "german": "German"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.key()` or `Object.values()` to get the object's key and values in an array. In your case, getting the values would be what you after

```
const dna = require("../dna.json")
    
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => { 
        if (message.author.bot) return;
            number = 100
            percentage = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) +1;

            dnaNumber = 5
            dnaResults = Math.floor (Math.random() * (dnaNumber - 1 + 1)) +1;
            var dnaEthnicities = Object.values(dna)[dnaResults-1] //add this
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                embed.setTitle('DNA Test ')
                embed.setColor('RANDOM')
                embed.setDescription('You are ' + percentage + '% ' + dnaEthnicities + '!')  //change to dnaEthnicities
                embed.setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(embed)
        
};
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand how that works!